# number of zeros runtime error

Tags: c, runtime-error

This is a function i made to count number of zeroes at the end of the factorial of a number b recursively.
However i'm getting runtime error due to the used code.Pardon my naivety but any help in this would be appreciated.

```
int noz(int b)
{ 
    int c=0;
    int e = b;
    if(e < 5)
       return 0; 
    while(e > 0)
       c = c + (e/5) + noz(e/5);
            return c; 
}
```

Comment: What kind of "number of zeroes"? There are infinitely many zeroes around the world...

Comment: no of zeros at the end of the factorial of number b..thanks for pointing that out i missed that in the desc.

Comment: Your programs (the current, and all of it's ancestors) invoke undefined behaviour. Stop guessing! You need to read a book to learn C. Otherwise, things that *might seem to work* on your system might detonate nuclear weapons on other systems.

Comment: This is the undefined behaviour, for those interested in helping: `c = c + (e/5) + noz(e/5);` violates 6.5p5. If an exceptional condition occurs during the evaluation of an expression (that is, if the
result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its
type), the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are encountering "runtime error" because:

```
int c;
...
while(e > 0)
   c = c + (e/5) + noz(e/5);  // <-- HERE
```

you are using uninitialized local variable `c`, which produces ***undefined behavior***.

You could zero-initialize this variable to prevent it happen:

```
int c = 0;
```

And also note that in case that argument of your function is greater or equal than `5`, this function doesn't return anything (thanks to [@Paul R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/253056/paul-r) for pointing this out) and another problem is that you have loop with the condition `e > 0` but the loop doesn't change the value of `e` making it infinite loop.

Your function could look like this instead (I'm not sure what exactly is the desired logic here):

```
int noz(int b)
{ 
    int c = 0;
    if (b < 5)
       return 0; 
    else
       return c + (b/5) + noz(b/5);
}
```

Comment: i did that but its stil giving the same error ..initially i didnt initialize c =0 as i thought after every recursive call the value of c will be 0 again

Comment: You're also not returning a value from noz - pay attention to your compiler warnings !

Comment: I'd imagine the result would be incorrect but how will this result in runtime error in the given program?

Comment: He's getting a **stack overflow** from the infinite loop with its recursive call.

Comment: @PaulR I don't see infinite loop - e is divided by 5 each time and stop condition is well-defined

Comment: @kshitij you have to define *input* before executing. Here it passes: http://ideone.com/z5Q0hd (though the mentioned errors are present)

Comment: `return c + (b/5) + noz(b/5);` //c is always 0.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: I tried to help as much as I could. I can't help with the logic of the function's body since I have really no idea what it is supposed to do.

Comment: @LihO i dont think its an infinte loop i got the program running by editing the return statement as you told.
but what you say also makes sense that e's value is never being 0 ,so im confused logically how the program is giving the correct output?
here. http://ideone.com/MzwGks

Comment: @kshitij: In your code, you use `return` in the first iteration of loop making it stop. The original code was just modifying value of `c`, never `return`ing anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
//count n! tail zero
int noz(int n){
    int count;

    if(n < 5) return 0;
    count = n / 5;
    return count + noz(count);
}
```